# Ubuntu mate 20.04 I am unable to delete the Trash files. I have tried sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash etc but the files remain

Tags: trash, removing

As in the title I have used the file manager with admin permissions and cannot delete files using shift delete. I have tried all the suggestions on Ask Ubuntu without success. help

Comment: "All the suggestions" - that's hard to believe. Explore your permission/ownership problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`. A `bash` script to answer "Why can't I Read/Write that file?".

Answer (score 0):

On MATE 21.04 the files in the trash bin are stored in `~/.local/share/Trash/files` I guess it would be the same for `MATE 20.04` it certainly is for ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

The `-r` arg is for removing a directory recursively. I doubt you want to remove the `files` directory and there is no need to use `sudo`.

Your command should simply be:
`rm ~/.local/share/Trash/files/[file_name]`

I just tried this command in terminal on MATE 21.04 with a file in the Trash Bin and it worked perfectly well.

Reference [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html) `rm`